# I want to set metadata to audio recording done in .m4a format in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, audiorecord, artwork

can any one help, i need to set the metadata to audio recording done by application.

I have a image which i need to set in the **artWork** of the recording.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What API are you using for writing the recording?

Comment: AVAudioRecorder from AVFoundation class of iOS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found implementations of **fetching** Metadata of AVAsset. But its **possible to set** 
AV MetaData using [AVMetaDataItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVMetadataItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html).
This class `MP42AVFImporter.m` in [This Example](https://bitbucket.org/galad87/subler/wiki/Home) has a method named -`(MP42Metadata*)convertMetadata` they have manipulated metadata and also they have added
there own artwork image... have a look...

Comment: This link is broken, anybody know how to do this properly?